# deeplink to google calendar

Tags: android, html, google-calendar-api

I would like to create a link to save an event to the android google calendar on my website. I found out how to create a link to the web interface but it won't open the app on my android:

```
https://calendar.google.com/calendar/r/eventedit?text=Test&dates=20180115T233000Z/20180115T233000Z&details=Details,+link:+http://example.com/&location=Paris&sf=true&output=xml
```

is it possible to create a deeplink like

```
calendar://event
```

and add a eventname, a description and a date to it?

I can do this with e.g facebook:

```
fb://profile
```

So it should work with google calendar aswell, right?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, the only way to access a specific event in Google Calendar is through an Intent. You can find more about this in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intents).

Comment: so basically I use `<a href="content://com.android.calendar/events/...">` on my website?

Comment: won't I need some kind of SDK to use the Calendar-Class?

Comment: Ha, it's from a website. My answer was from another android app, I'm not sure that the Google Calendar provides a scheme like FB.